# Jimp.read creating error - zlib binding closed

Tags: javascript, image-manipulation, discord.js

I am working using Node and Discord.js, making edits to the source code of a Discord bot for a client.  As such I won't be able to provide the full source files as the vast majority of the code isn't mine and I'd rather not release the client's code just in case - but I'll be posting the snippets written by me that are relevant to the question.

The task involves making the bot generate an image highlighting the 'daily' items in the Fortnite game shop.  Basically, a background/template image, which will have the images of various shop items overlayed onto boxes in the template image.  To accomplish this, I've been attempting to use [Jimp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp) for the image manipulation/generation involved.  However, I've run across a strange issue that only seems to be a problem when the images came from the API that provides the Fortnite item pngs.

This API returns (among other things) a URL to the image, which was what I initially tried to use to read from with Jimp.  (Note that I can't actually provide any links to the API docs as it's in a closed beta; I only have access to it because the client gave me their token so I could work on it.)  `Jimp.read` is meant to take an img URL that it processes into a Jimp image - and this seems to work fine when I use an image URL from *any other source*.  When feeding it the URL from this API, though, it causes an exception which `console.log`s as:

```
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: zlib binding closed
```

(followed by the rest of a stack trace, which I'll post in full down below).

I've been beating my head against a wall for several hours now trying to break through this, Googling, trying to create workarounds, try out alternative libraries, but have still not been able to get anywhere.  I tried loading the image into a Buffer and feeding *that* into `Jimp.read`, but get the exact same error, word for word.  Tried using the `new Jimp( ... )` constructor instead but still didn't work.

I've also been Googling to try and find an answer but the `zlib binding closed` error seems to be *extremely* uncommon and there were very few mentions of it in *any* context, and no mentions of it in relation to Jimp that I could find.  Googling "zlib binding closed" within quotes provided me only 19 results period.  If nothing else, if anyone knows what this error *means*, that would help me have a better idea where to look to fix it.

I've tried looking into alternatives to the Jimp library, but as far as JavaScript image manipulating libraries go, the Canvas API requires a DOM object and Caman I just couldn't get to install.

I don't generally ask things on StackOverflow but I couldn't find instances of this problem anywhere.  Possible solutions or even just explanations of what the error could mean would be extremely helpful, also if anyone has suggestions for a good alternative to Jimp in the case I can't fix this.

(Code snippets/stack traces below, I probably missed some important stuff since I'm tired and completely brainfried from working on this, so let me know if you need anything else from me)

**URL Attempt:**

```
Jimp.read("https://image.fnbr.co/outfit/5b90ec38262b40c2dcc98379/icon.png")
    .then(image => {
        message.channel.send("jimp", {
            file: image
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });") // Should just return a URL string
    .then(image => {
        message.channel.send("jimp", {
            file: image
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

**Buffer Attempt:**

```
request.get("https://image.fnbr.co/outfit/5b90ec38262b40c2dcc98379/icon.png", function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var buffer = new Buffer(body);
        Jimp.read(buffer)
            .then(image => {
                message.channel.send("jimp", {
                    file: image
                });
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    } else {
        console.log("8(");
    }
});
```

^ Ultimately the above will be getting the image URLs based on the 'daily' results from the shop but for now I'm just trying to get them to work on a hard-coded URL.  All URLs from that API follow the same format as the one used here.

**Full `console.log(err)` Console Output:**

```
{ AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: zlib binding closed
    at Inflate._processChunk (C:\Users\(user)\Documents\dev\(project)\node_modules\pngjs\lib\sync-inflate.js:108:3)
    at zlibBufferSync (C:\Users\(user)\Documents\dev\(project)\node_modules\pngjs\lib\sync-inflate.js:151:17)
    at inflateSync (C:\Users\(user)\Documents\dev\(project)\node_modules\pngjs\lib\sync-inflate.js:155:10)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\(user)\Documents\dev\(project)\node_modules\pngjs\lib\parser-sync.js:79:20)
    at Object.exports.read [as image/png] (C:\Users\(user)\Documents\dev\(project)\node_modules\pngjs\lib\png-sync.js:10:10)
    at Jimp.parseBitmap (C:\Users\(user)\Documents\dev\(project)\node_modules\@jimp\core\dist\utils\image-bitmap.js:117:53)
    at new Jimp (C:\Users\(user)\Documents\dev\(project)\node_modules\@jimp\core\dist\index.js:425:32)
    at _construct (C:\Users\(user)\Documents\dev\(project)\node_modules\@jimp\core\dist\index.js:100:393)
    at C:\Users\(user)\Documents\dev\(project)\node_modules\@jimp\core\dist\index.js:885:5
    at Promise (<anonymous>)
  generatedMessage: false,
  name: 'AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]',
  code: 'ERR_ASSERTION',
  actual: undefined,
  expected: true,
  operator: '==',
  methodName: 'constructor' }
```

Managing packages with npm, running from a Windows computer.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchinfo/ "There is a huge amount of text inside your question. Your real problem lies only in a few instructions, and most of the text posted is completely irrelevant to the resolution of your issue. It only serves as noise, and makes it harder for those trying to answer your question."

Comment: your issue is related to using PNG, I'm having the same one. I tried using JPEG and it works fine. Did you find a solution for PNG case by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. 
In my case I was testing with node 10.15.3 but when I pkged my app, the node version embedded was on version 8. Since ZLIB is not available in that version, the assert failed. That is the reason why I was seeing the error.